# Executing arbitrary blocks of python code with RubyPython

Tags: python, ruby, rubypython

I'm trying to use the RubyPython module (https://github.com/halostatue/rubypython) to execute Python code from within a Ruby script.  I have the module all set up correctly, but am very confused how to use it.

If I had a block of Python code as text, say:

```
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y * y

z = multiply(x, y)
```

How would I be able to pass this to Python to execute with 'x' and 'y' defined dynamically in Ruby, and then be able to retrieve the value of 'z'?

**Edit per comment request**
So far, this works and makes sense to me:

```
RubyPython.start(python_exe: "/usr/bin/python2.6")
cPickle = RubyPython.import("cPickle")
p cPickle.dumps("Testing RubyPython.").rubify
RubyPython.stop # stop the Python interpreter
```

That gives me an output of `"S'Testing RubyPython.'\n."`

And I can run very simple commands like this:

```
RubyPython.start(python_exe: "/usr/bin/python2.6")
x = 3
y = x * x * x
print "y = %d" % y
RubyPython.stop # stop the Python interpreter
```

That gives me an output of `"y = 27"`, as expected.

But once I try to define a method in python, I just get a series of errors:

```
RubyPython.start(python_exe: "/usr/bin/python2.6")
def my_multiply(x, y):
  return x * y * y
z = my_multiply(2, 3)
print "z = %d" % z
RubyPython.stop # stop the Python interpreter
```

I get `syntax error, unexpected ':'`

So how would I execute this block of python code using this module?  And more importantly, how would I pass values in from Ruby into the Python code that is executing?

Comment: Can you show _what you did_ when you followed the advice in https://github.com/halostatue/rubypython   (Synopsis, Basic Usage, Specific Python Version, etc.) ?
Therein are quite a few examples that should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Is it just me, or are you entering Python code where the Ruby interpreter is expecting Ruby code. Your error "syntax error, unexepected ':'" seems to agree with my basis. I don't see any examples of RubyPython where it works that way - you should be doing that as a string and passing it to RubyPython in some way I would imagine. **edit** The first example you list (where you're printing with Python formatting style) is perfectly valid and legal Ruby - thus it works. The `:` is out of place in the second example and the Ruby interpreter is complaining.

Comment: Brandon - my hypothesis is the same as yours.  I just can't figure out how I would pass that code as a string to RubyPython - that's the crux of my question!

Comment: I see now, I was looking into it myself but see nothing as well. It looks like it just enable you to import and call Python modules if I understand the docs correctly. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no answer has been made, and I managed to find *something* (although a very ugly something at that).

I'm not sure at all if this is the intended method to use `RubyPython` but I was able to get things to function by doing the following set of tasks:

```
 > RubyPython.start
 > RubyPython::Python.PyRun_SimpleString <<-PYTHON
*> def test():
*>     print("Hello, World")
*> PYTHON
 > main = RubyPython.import("__main__")
 > main.test()
 >>> Hello, World!
 > RubyPython::Python.PyRun_SimpleString <<-PYTHON
*> def my_mult(x, y):
*>     return x * y
*> PYTHON
 > main.my_mult(10, 20).rubify
 >>> 200
```

Again, whether this is the "correct" way to do it, or not is up for debate - but it worked.